# Is it possible to record video and upload it to youtube using actionscript 3 and php?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, air

Can i upload videos to youtube using an as3 based Adobe Air application, record it, send it to a server and then submit to a youtube account channel?

Are there any tutorials on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer: It is going to take some effort, but you have the pieces from the sounds of it.

Youtube Upload API: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Uploading_Videos

Flash Recording API:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetStream.html#publish()

I don't know if you are familiar with flash recording, but if you have an installation of `Flash Media Server`, the publishing portion is really pretty simple. Grab `Camera`, attach to `NetStream`, `publish()`.

Once your video is on the server, it is simply a matter of implementing the required youtube API calls on the PHP end. I have never worked with their API.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i don't think will be possible for this project to setup a Flash Media Server, do you think will it be still possible?

Comment: If it is a cost issue, Adobe offers FMS for free with limited concurrent connections, also Red5: http://www.red5.org/ is an open-source alternative.

If you are constrained by time and server configuration, not really. I know AIR gives you some more access to the filesystem than Flash, but I think you will have major issues trying to do this all from Actionscript.