# Publish video from AS3 to Youtube

Tags: actionscript-3, video, youtube

I read some examples to upload videos (from the user's disk) to yotube, using an AS3 app.

http://gdata-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gdata/YouTubeApi/YouTubeApi.mxml

I need to **publish** (into my youtube channel) a video generated with AS3, using the user's webcam.

¿Some example or idea?

Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435139/is-it-possible-to-record-video-and-upload-it-to-youtube-using-actionscript-3-and

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Everything you need is there, good luck !